# Export a tab from another excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working template (excel based) which uses a macro to have the user to export another tab from another excel:

It worked fine, but my issue is that one of the excels we need to copy data in from changes names of the tabs all the time.. e.g. Export (1), Export (2).
Can I change the code below, so it takes in all tabs irrespectively of name?

AND in the same action rename the tab to 'Master export'

Current code:

```
Sub export_sheet()

'switch off screen updating and alerts

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'delete existing sheets (rename as needed)

Call delete_sheet

'set source and destination

Dim Destination As String
Destination = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    
'copy all sheets in range

Dim Worksheets As Variant
ReDim Worksheets(1)
Worksheets(1) = "Export"

Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

Dim i As Variant
For i = 1 To UBound(Worksheets)
OpenBook.Sheets(Worksheets(i)).Copy _
After:=Workbooks(Destination).Sheets(Workbooks(Destination).Sheets.Count)
Next i
    End If

'close source workbook
OpenBook.Close False

'switch on screen updating and alerts

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: *Dim Worksheets As Variant* **I strongly suggest to use a different name** for this variable, to avoid any kind of conflict with object [Worksheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.worksheets)

Comment: Remove the Worksheets array (BTW, not a really good idea to give a variable a name that supersedes a global variable). Loop on OpenBook.Worksheets with a `For Each` to treat all worksheets.

Comment: Why declare `i` a variant?

Comment: First of all thanks for your proposals - im really not an expert making these codes, so im sure it can be done dfifferent.

But trying to remove the above just gives me an error, might try to start from scratch